# Firebase is installed globally, I want to use a different google account for different projects, but unable to

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

I have Firebase installed globally because I will be using it for multiple projects.  One of my projects is already logged in Firebase.  I created another project, but I am using a different account for it. When I hit `$ firebase login` the root of the new project, I get this in terminal: **Already logged in as xxx@gmail.com**

I have a *.firebaserc* with:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "new-project"
  }
}
```

How do I log out of the other account? Or specify that this Firebase project needs to use a different login? The login seems to be global.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind...

`$ firebase login --reauth`

Did the trick